How to use an installed requirement in bazel BUILD file?
I am creating a new bazel workspace for a python codebase. The codebase has multiple folders with respective BUILD files. Each of the BUILD file has different external dependencies. These external dependencies are defined in requirements file and installed using pip.parse in Module.bazel. However, one thing that I am not clear on is how to use these dependencies in the BUILD files.
I have a WORKSPACE file with the following content:
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = "3b8b4cdc991bc9def8833d118e4c850f1b7498b3d65d5698eea92c3528b8cf2c",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-0.30.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.30.0/rules_python-0.30.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "py_repositories")

py_repositories()

and MODULE.bazel file with the following:
module(name = "my_module", version = "1.0")

bazel_dep(name = "rules_python", version = "0.31.0")

pip = use_extension("@rules_python//python/extensions:pip.bzl", "pip")

python = use_extension("@rules_python//python/extensions:python.bzl", "python")

python.toolchain(
    configure_coverage_tool = True,
    python_version = "3.9",
)

pip.parse(
    hub_name = "pip",
    python_version = "3.9",
    requirements_lock = "//:requirements.txt",
)

use_repo(pip, "pip")

I also have a requirements.txt file with only dependency mentioned "tink==1.9.0". My bazel version is 7.0.1 and python version is 3.9.6.
I have tried
adding load("@pip//:requirements.bzl", "requirement") in BUILD file and using it like: requirement("tink") in the deps arg.
For this, I get the following error:
no such package '@@[unknown repo 'pip_39_protobuf' requested from @@rules_python~0.31.0~pip~pip_39_tink]//': The repository '@@[unknown repo 'pip_39_protobuf' requested from @@rules_python~0.31.0~pip~pip_39_tink]' could not be resolved: No repository visible as '@pip_39_protobuf' from repository '@@rules_python~0.31.0~pip~pip_39_tink'
Any help is much appreciated!

Is that the full error output? Similar errors often come after the root cause. It's often helpful if you quote the entire command and its output with triple backticks (sorry I can't figure out how to show an example in a comment).
